# Why bootstrap simple full width layout causes overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As I'm struggling to understand front end development concepts I have the following question:

I'm developing a simple layout with Bootstrap . The page is going to be in a full width layout so after I started coding i've noticed a horizontal scrollbar in the window. Hacking it with overflow-hidden doesn't seem right to me. Can someone explain why this happens and how to avoid it?

Side question, is this the right markup for a header like the one below?
///////
Header
//////

```
---Link----------------------------------------------------------------LINK
---Logo----------main-navigation---------------------------------------Link

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div id="top-header">
                <a href="#">1</a>
                <a href="#">2</a>
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-header" class="row">
                    <div id="left-header" class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_site_url().'/wp-content/themes/test-theme/img/logo.png'?>" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right-header" class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="main-navigation">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu('main-menu'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="content">
    Content here
</div>
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap this html in one div with this class `container-fluid`

```
     <div id="wrapper">
                <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
                    <div id="top-header">
                        <a href="#">1</a>
                        <a href="#">2</a>
                        <a href="#">3</a>
                    </div>
     <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="bottom-header" class="row">
                            <div id="left-header" class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_site_url().'/wp-content/themes/test-theme/img/logo.png'?>" alt=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="right-header" class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="main-navigation">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu('main-menu'); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
</div>
                </header><!-- #masthead -->
        <div id="content">
            Content here
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried it before but now all the elements inside the container-fluid get a left-right 15px padding . I still want full width without padding

Answer (score 1):

Do as @Lalji Tadhani suggested. Then you make a css selector like this:

```
.noPadding {
    padding:0px;
}
```

Now you can add this class to your html elements where you don't need the padding.
You will always run in things that don't suit you when making use of frameworks. You just have to find a clean way to work around it.

Regarding to your question about the header: 
Maybe it is semantically more correct to make use of a unordered list  for the links. But the rest seems fine.

Comment: I've thought about using a ul , but the is it a good practice to use inline-block and add a big padding to the first? Isn't cleaner using floats?

Comment: I would not dare to say, that is the way how I learned but. But hold on to what you have right now. Looks good and I don't think it makes a hell of a difference.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but i'm coming from the "back-end" area , and trying to adapt as many best-practices as i can. Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

There must be an margin issue .
add this style in your page:

```
body  {  
margin : 0px;  
}
```

In my opinion it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different class `.no-row` and give it all the properties of `.row` minus the padding.
`.no-row {width:100%; padding:0!important; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;}`